# How do I inform Tokio about an event in a C-owned thread?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I use a C library which provides an API to call user provided function in a thread created by that C library. I cannot handle events inside the callback because it should not block the thread, so I want some way to inform the Tokio event loop that my callback was called.

How can I do that?

More precisely I have:

```
fn register_callback_to_run_inside_c_thread<F>(callback_f: F)
where
    F: FnMut() + Send + UnwindSafe + 'static,
{
    unimplemented!();
}
```

I want to pass a closure inside `register_callback_to_run_inside_c_thread` to inform Tokio about the event.

First I tried:

```
let (mut tx, rx) = watch::channel("hello");
register_callback_to_run_inside_c_thread(move || {
    tx.broadcast("world").unwrap();
});
```

This code doesn't compile because it uses `RefCell` somewhere inside.

I also tried to use `lazy` to start a function inside Tokio. That code compiles, but crashes during runtime because `lazy` should be executed inside threads created by Tokio but the callback runs inside a thread created by the C library.

Is there any way to inform Tokio about the event?

Comment: Can you please provide a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) of the not working code? A [mcve] would be really nice here to see the actual error (maybe you can paste it as well).

Comment: I suppose/think/just an idea that you must use [`Registration`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.18/tokio/reactor/struct.Registration.html)